# Overriding class in chain?

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
.mainClass a.customizeIt span {
background: transparent url('../images/myimage.png') no-repeat;
color: #ffffff;
display: block;
font-size: 13px;
}
```

Is there some way to do another version of the above so no background image is used?

```
.mainClass a.customizeIt span {
color: #ffffff;
display: block;
font-size: 13px;
}
```

How should the second version be referenced in the element?

-- EDIT --
Is the following possible so there is no background and I can reuse color, display, and font-size?

```
.mainClass a.customizeIt a.no-bg span {
background: none;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would create another class `.no-bg` with the rule `background-image: none`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you main?

html

```
<a class="customizeIt" href="#"><span>sample1</span></a>
```

*used the class `no-bg` in the part you want to remove the background image just show below*

```
<a class="customizeIt no-bg" href="#"><span>sample2</span></a>
```

css

```
.mainClass a.customizeIt span {
background: transparent url('../images/myimage.png') no-repeat;
color: #fff;
display: block;
font-size: 13px;
}

.mainClass a.no-bg span {background-image:none !important}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the background as none otherwise it'll just inherit it from the previous class.

```
.mainClass a.customizeIt span {
    background: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Comment: That will just override the other class.  They both need to be used in the same page.